# Include DirectX installation in my Plugin installation

Tags: plugins, installation, directx, cab, firebreath

I have a browser plugin written in FireBreath and have a msi package genearted.

I packed the msi in a cab file in order to provide IE users automatic installation.

However, my plugin use DirectX, so I would like to install DirectX along with my plugin.

How do I trigger the DirectX installation? from the msi installer? the inf file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: xp comes with directx and so you only need to install it for win2k. I'd just ask your 3 users on win2k to install it themselves!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/07/31/8797084.aspx

or this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/06/05/8576818.aspx

How about this? http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_directx9.htm

Those are the first three results on google when searching for "wix installer directx" and they seem to fit the bill nicely...